# How to increase a particular column each cell value by one, based on a certain condition in python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
In [235]: df
Out[235]:
   a  b  c
0  2  2  6
1  1  0  3
2  2  2  7
3  0  2  0
4  0  1  8
```

I would like to increase column 'c' each cell value in dataframe by one based on condition that if column 'c' cell value more than 5. If column'c'each cell value less than 5 then column 'c'cell value become zero
eg cell(3,1)=6, then 6>5, cell(3,1) become 7. And cell(3,2)=3 then 3<5, cell(3,2) become 0, ...i hope u understood
Output something like that..

```
In [237]: df
Out[237]:
   a  b  c
0  2  2  7
1  1  0  0
2  2  2  8
3  0  2  0
4  0  1  9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply function and define a function for your logic.

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,1,2,0,0], 'b':[2,0,2,2,1],'c':[6,3,7,0,8]})

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   a  b  c
0  2  2  6
1  1  0  3
2  2  2  7
3  0  2  0
4  0  1  8

In [10]: df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: x+1 if x>5 else 0)

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   a  b  c
0  2  2  7
1  1  0  0
2  2  2  8
3  0  2  0
4  0  1  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
df['c']=np.where(df.c>5,df.c+1,0)
df
   a  b  c
0  2  2  7
1  1  0  0
2  2  2  8
3  0  2  0
4  0  1  9
```